# ng-repeat not showing any contents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to put the content in my MongoDB using Mongoose and AngularJS. So far everything seems to be working but when I use `ng-repeat` the table comes up blank.

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="FormController">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="sensordata in sensordatas track by $index">
            <td>{{sensordata.topic}}</td> 
            <td>{{sensordata.message}}</td>
            <td>{{sensordata.when}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('FormApp', []);

app.controller("FormController", function ($http, $scope){
$http.get("/api/sensordata")
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.sensordatas = response;
    });
})
```

**server.js**

```
//Data Schema
var dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    topic: String,
    message: Number,
    when: Date
}, {collection: "sensordata"});

var sensordata =mongoose.model('sensordata', dataSchema);

//$HTTP GET function
app.get('/api/sensordata', function(req, res) {
    sensordata.find(function (err, data) {
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

This is the data I get when I print my data to console. http://i67.tinypic.com/2rhlpwg.png I don't understand the footer of the data.

Comment: try `$scope.sensordatas = response.data;`.

Comment: What part of the code should I make this change?

Comment: in your app.js, just add `.data` to your response callback.

Comment: You're the best!!! Thanks for much!

Comment: Got so excited there. Thanks so* much.

Answer (score -1):

can you pleae put wrapper around your html view code for app

```
<div ng-app="app"><div class="container" ng-controller="FormController">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="sensordata in sensordatas track by $index">
            <td>{{sensordata.topic}}</td> 
            <td>{{sensordata.message}}</td>
            <td>{{sensordata.when}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry didn't get that.